# Position of leftAxis labels

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I have a `LineChartView` with labels on the `leftAxis`. I would like to have an offset on the chart and then use the free space to show the labels. I currently have the following:

```
chartView.leftAxis.labelPosition = YAxis.LabelPosition.outsideChart
chartView.leftAxis.xOffset = 12
```

`labelPosition` only offers outside- and insideChart.

But I would like to move the labels a bit more to the left, is it possibly to specify an offset for the labels or somehow move them a bit more to the left?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a much cleaner solution: 
1. create this class:

```
class MyIndexFormatter: IndexAxisValueFormatter {

   open override func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String
   {
        return "\(value)     "
   }    
}
```

2. In your controller:

   ```
   chartView.leftAxis.valueFormatter = MyIndexFormatter()
   ```

result:
[image]

Comment: Yeah, I already have IndexAxisValueFormatter subclass for the leftAxis as I wrote below. I guess I will take this solution for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The values on y-axis can be stored as a string, and then you can add whitespaces to each value to shift them to the left.

```
 var yvalues: [String] = [String]()
 yvalues.append("0    ")
 yvalues.append("1    ")
 yvalues.append("2    ")
 yvalues.append("3    ")
 yvalues.append("4    ")
 yvalues.append("5    ")
 yvalues.append("6    ")
 yvalues.append("7    ")
 yvalues.append("8    ")
 yvalues.append("9    ")
 yvalues.append("10    ")
 chartView.leftAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: yvalues)
```

now there is much more space between the leftaxis and the graph, than between the rightaxis and the graph: 
[image]

Comment: I thought about doing this as well, since I already have a valueFormatter for the leftAxis that implements `stringForValue`. But this doesn't feel like a clean solution though, I wonder if there is any other way to solve this.